# How to add Inner Shadow for Text with ImageMagick in PHP

Tags: php, imagemagick

I have found this bellow Code from [http://www.imagemagick.org/](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=23417&p=98450#p98514)

```
convert button.png \( +clone -background black -shadow 75x0+0-5 \) \
\( -clone 0 -alpha off -virtual-pixel black -blur 0x2 -alpha on \) \
-delete 0 -background none -layers merge +repage button3.png
```

Output of above code is:

[image]

And i have tried this with PHP

```
    $textLayer = new Imagick();
    $textLayer->newImage(500, 400, new ImagickPixel('transparent'));

    $draw = new ImagickDraw();
    $draw->setFillColor(#000);
    $draw->setFillOpacity(0.7);
    $draw->setTextKerning(0);
    $draw->setFont('impact.ttf');
    $draw->setFontSize(110);
    $draw->skewY(-90);
    $draw->setGravity(Imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER);

    $textLayer->annotateImage($draw, -10, 0, 30, 'WELCOME');
    $textLayer->setImageFormat('png');

    header("Content-Type: image/png");
    echo $textLayer`
```

I am seeing text with transparent background, please help me to fix the code to have inner shadow. Thanks.

Comment: why not use `CSS`, it would be better to do this client side I would think

Comment: Apply a shadow after your result. See http://us3.php.net/manual/en/imagick.shadowimage.php. The apply a blur. See http://us3.php.net/manual/en/imagick.blurimage.php. Then merge the images. See http://us3.php.net/manual/en/imagick.mergeimagelayers.php. Sorry, I do not code Imagick. So I can only point you to the equivalent commands. You can also try my script texteffect2 that has lots of features in a PHP exec() command. See http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php

Comment: @fmw42 hi thanks for your kind reply, i have already looked your script, the problem is i can export your effect only as file, but i want to only display this on screen only. so i cannot use your script.